# Python - Send email with multiple image attachments

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime

I'm trying to send an email using Python with multiple image attachments. However with the code below I am able to include the first image in the body of the text but the second image gets attached to the email as an attachment.  Is there a way I can get both images in the body of the HTML?  Below is my current code.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

strFrom = 'user@provider.com'
strTo = 'user@provider.com'

msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'Test message'
msgRoot['From'] = 'user@provider.com'
msgRoot['To'] = 'user@provider.com'
msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'

msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

msgText = MIMEText('This is the alternative plain text message.')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

msgText = MIMEText('<b>Test HTML with Images</b><br><br>'
                   '<img src="cid:image1">'
                   '<br>'
                   '<br>'
                   '<img src="cid:image2">'
                   '<br>'
                   '<br>'
                   'Sending Two Attachments', 'html')

msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

fp = open('image1.png', 'rb')
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage)

fp = open('image2.png', 'rb')
msgImage2 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image2>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage2)

import smtplib
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
smtp.sendmail(strFrom, strTo, msgRoot.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: I am not really sure, the code seems okay. I found this [article about emailing multiple inline images in python](http://dogdogfish.com/python-2/emailing-multiple-inline-images-in-python/), hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code should be:

```
fp = open('image1.png', 'rb')
msgImage1 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage1)

fp = open('image2.png', 'rb')
msgImage2 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image2>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage2)
```

You need to specify it's `image1` instead of just `image`

Comment: Exactly, that's what I mean. I was at work and couldn't edit this very well. Thanks Barry!

Comment: The example code is almost correct,the 'add_header' line needs to refer to msgImage1 and msgImage2 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change `MIMEMultipart` to `mixed`. I have code to include images and use mixed mode works well for me.

```
msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
```